# Text coming out of paragraph tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I'm using masonry layout for my website and I'm generating the boxes from php. whenever i have a lot of text on one of the p tags or the box, the text overflows out of the tag. This is the live site: `http://uneraportoj.com/index2.php` 
I tried setting a padding and break-word is not working. please help

Comment: Make a fiddle or post a link to your page please. There's to much code to take in + you have php tags.

Comment: @lonut i posted a link to the problem page. Thanks.

Comment: how do you want to handle it? do you want a scroll or box's height should stretch according to  content height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.grid-item.masonry-brick {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

... or maybe

```
.grid-item { /* main.css : 58 */
    /* max-height: 1430px; */
}
```

Comment: Thanks this kinda worked but now i can scroll up or down. how come?

Comment: This is the correct answer, unless you just want to chop the text off. In that case, overflow: hidden;

Comment: Well, you didn't exactly specify what you wanted. See my edit for another possible fix.

Comment: @isherwood thanks a lot for your help but if i dont do max-height, instead of the space from the divs to the pagination being 20px, it usually is a lot more than that. I will upload the changes now and maybe you can take a look for possible fixes??

Comment: @isherwood nevermind, it seems to work fine now after a couple of uploads. Thankssss